# Convert array of numerics to normal fraction

Tags: php, math, php-7

I have array of three elements:

1. integer
2. numerator
3. denominator

How without stupid ways convert wrong fraction to normal?

Example: [1, 7, 4] -> [2, 3, 4]. Numerator/denominator.

Comment: Please provide an example array, we simply cannot help with that question alone.

Comment: And an example of what you want the result to be

Comment: Why not write some code to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to get a common denominator?

Comment: @Hudson yes....

Comment: You'd have to have a number array for all multiples of the number and possibly search the array for matching numbers on the other fraction. get the number and simplify from there

Comment: This all seems very far fetched though, can't you just validate input as to not allow the numerator to be higher than the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if this is what your wanting.

```
 <?php 

     function cleanFraction($value , $numerator , $denominator)
     {
          while($numerator >= $denominator)
          {
              $numerator -= $denominator;
              $value++;
          }
          return array($value , $numerator , $denominator);
     }

 ?>
```